# File input change event is not firing from electron app but from angular

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, angular6

I have a image upload functionally in Angular 6 based electron application. Like below

```
<img #userphoto id="userphoto"  alt="" />

<input type="file" name="userphoto" id="add-photo" accept="image/png, image/jpg" (change)="changeImage($event)" />

<input type="file" name="userphoto" id="change-photo" accept="image/png, image/jpg" (change)="changeImage($event)" />
```

what am doing with `changeImage()` method  is setting the `src` of the image ( #userphoto). First am adding image using the first file input (id="add-photo") and am able to set src of the image. Once the image added am trying to change the previously added image using second file input (id="change-photo" ), but in this case `change` event is not firing.

Please note that the event firing from angular (when we user ng serve and browser) , but not working in electron.

Comment: Does the event not fire at all when running in Electron? Or is it firing, but not setting the image?

Comment: Yes. event fires at the first time. It is not fired second time from second input. Both inputs are modifying same image. The first one is to add image, the second one to change/update image.

Comment: Can you create a minimum sample project with this issue?